# Rename Sharepoint folder using ClientContext

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

been stuck for this for a while. I need to rename a SharePoint folder using ClientContext. I created a function like so:

```
Public Function renameFolder(_folders As ListItemCollection, _newFolderName As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Using _clientContext As New ClientContext(vSharepointSite)
            AddHandler _clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest, AddressOf vClaimsHelper.clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest
            Dim _folder = _folders(0)
            _folder.Item("Title") = _newFolderName
            _folder.Item("FileLeafRef") = _newFolderName
            _folder.Item("DisplayName") = _newFolderName
            _folder.Update()

            _clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

        End Using
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

This function takes a folder collection (actually I pass a collection of only 1 folder) and the new folder name. The function executes well. Inspecting the `_folder` after the `ExecuteQuery`, everything looks as expected. However nothing happens in SharePoint, meaning that the folder name remains the original name.

Any suggestions?

Best regards and....HAPPY NEW YEAR!!!!
Ariel

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `List Item` ( `_folder` variable in your example) *is associated with* `Folder` object.

### How to determine whether `List Item` is associated with a `Folder` object

```
Using ctx As New ClientContext(webUrl)
    Dim list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle)
    Dim item = list.GetItemById(itemId)
    ctx.Load(item.Folder)
    ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Dim isFolderItem = Not item.Folder.ServerObjectIsNull.Value

End Using
```

### How to rename Folder using SharePoint CSOM

The following example demonstrates how to rename a `Folder`:

```
Public Sub RenameFolder(folder As Folder, folderName As String)
    Dim ctx = folder.Context
    Dim folderItem = folder.ListItemAllFields
    folderItem("FileLeafRef") = folderName
    folderItem("Title") = folderName
    folderItem.Update()
    ctx.ExecuteQuery()
End Sub
```

Usage

```
    Using ctx As New ClientContext(webUrl)
        Dim folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl)
        RenameFolder(folder, "Orders")
    End Using
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Vadim. I forgot to mention we are still using versoin 14 of the Microsoft.Sharepoint and Client libraries. In any case, your answer highly motivates me to migrate to version 15. Best regards!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BaseName` field to rename the folder.

```
_folder.Item("BaseName") = _newFolderName
```